# Populate spinner with different cursors

Tags: android, database, cursor, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I have a spinner that I populate with a cursor from database sqlite column, this works OK, but isn't ideal. I added another spinner to select a column and show it in spinner, but this is my problem when I build the adapter. This is my code:

```
    cursor = myDB.obtenerColumna(getBaseContext(),elemento);   
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "columna", "columnb", "columnc", "columnd" };
    menudesplegable.setPrompt(getText(R.string.seleccionaEtiqueta)); 

   SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,cursor,
            columns, new int[] {android.R.id.text1});    

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource
            (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

I get columns from database correctly, but if I pass a cursor from other column the app fail building adapter. I try pass only name column in String[] but fail too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this:

```
/**
 * Crea el menú desplegable para seleccionar tiqueta.
 */
public void construirMenuDesplegable(String elemento) {
    // get items of database using selected element in other spinner
    cursor = myDB.obtenerColumna(getBaseContext(), elemento);
    menudesplegable.setPrompt(getText(R.string.seleccionaEtiqueta));

    // Create adapter
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cursor,
            new String[] { elemento }, new int[] { android.R.id.text1 });

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Indicate adapter
    menudesplegable.setAdapter(adapter);

    try {
        myDB.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("miError", "Error al cerrar db", e);
    }
}

/**
 * Build spinner for select a element for show in other spinner.
 */
public void construirMenuDesplegable2() {
    // Create adapter
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.listables, R.layout.custom_spinner);
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Indicate adapter
    menudesplegable2.setAdapter(adapter2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do the whole thing.

once the first spinner is populated just **close** the **cursor**.

`mycursor.close();`

then repeat same logic to the second spinner.